# Angular 2 RC1, passing url parameter separate with a question mark

Tags: angular

I have users that enter on my web app with an url like this:

```
http://myapp/#/home?email=exemple@test.com
```

Since rc1 I can't retrieve the email parameter and my browser throw me:

```
EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): ObjectUnsubscribedError
```

My `Route` is something like this:

```
{path: '/home', component: homeComponent}
```

I try to retrieve it with `RouteSegment` in my `Component`, so is there a way since rc1 to get the email parameter in the url separate with a question mark ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query parameters are not supported in RC.1 `@angular/router`.

This router will be replaced *again* soon anyway.

Comment: @EEllie The new router is not yet included in RC2 but can be used with RC2 (and RC1). I haven't tried query parameters yet but I'm sure they are already or will be soon supported. The new router makes quite a good impression already despite early alpha state and a few known issues.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could change your url into something like this

```
http://myapp/home/email=exemple@test.com
```

and then parse the last parameter, `email=exemple@test.com`

Comment: Yes I could, but my question was about using query parameters in order to better meet the url syntax

Comment: I see, then you have to wait another month or so until the router is fixed/released